# Passing integer types to a mex function

Tags: c++, matlab, int, mex

I'm currently using a mex function where integers are sent as a parameter by first converting it to `int` type with:

```
a = int32(10);
foo(a);
```

Where foo receives/checks `a` by using:

```
void get_integer_scalar(int &scalar,const mxArray *mat_buf) {
    // Check input
    if (mxIsClass(mat_buf,"int32")) {
        if (mxGetN(mat_buf) == 1 &&  mxGetM(mat_buf) == 1) {
            // At this point, input is correct
            scalar = *((int *)mxGetData(mat_buf));
        } else {
            mexErrMsgTxt("Integer scalar is not of size == [1 1].\n");
        }
    } else {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Integer scalar is not int32.\n");
    }
}
```

Now, it just sort of dawned upon me that the `int` type is machine dependent, so the line `scalar = *((int *)mxGetData(mat_buf));` might be unsafe (or is it? I'm trying to not make assumptions about how `int32()` works in matlab). Is there a safe way to pass a standard `int` type to a mex file or should I be using a 32 bit int type like `int32_t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mxGetScalar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetscalar.html), which returns a double value, no matter what the input type, which you can cast without worry.

```
double mxGetScalar(const mxArray *pm); // the type of data in pm doesn't matter
```

> In C, `mxGetScalar` returns a double. If real elements in the `mxArray` are of a type other than `double`, **`mxGetScalar` automatically converts the scalar value into a `double`**. To preserve the original data representation of the scalar, cast the return value to the desired data type.

Just check the number of elements, and you don't even need a type check (but I would use `mxIsInt32` for that, if needed):

```
#include <mex.h>

void get_integer_scalar(int &scalar,const mxArray *mat_buf) {
    // Check input
    if (!mxIsInt32(mat_buf))
        mexPrintf("Integer scalar is not int32, but that's OK.\n");

    if (mxGetNumberOfElements(mat_buf) == 1) {
        scalar = mxGetScalar(mat_buf);
    } else {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Integer scalar is not of size == [1 1].\n");
    }
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int val;
    if (nrhs>0)
    {
        get_integer_scalar(val,prhs[0]); // type of prhs[0] does not matter
        mexPrintf("%d\n",val);
    }
}
```

---

To answer your question, MATLAB's `int32` is obviously not machine dependent, but as you pointed out there are no guarantees that C++ `int` will be 32-bit.  I think `mxGetScalar` addresses this for scalars, but for arrays (when you need a pointer safely casted) I think you are right that you can use `<stdint.h>` or `<cstdint>`, which set `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`, etc. Visual Studio does `typedef int int32_t;`.

MATLAB also has a header for this purpose: `tmwtypes.h`. It sets the following fixed-width types:

```
/*=======================================================================*
 * Fixed width word size data types:                                     *
 *   int8_T, int16_T, int32_T     - signed 8, 16, or 32 bit integers     *
 *   uint8_T, uint16_T, uint32_T  - unsigned 8, 16, or 32 bit integers   *
 *   real32_T, real64_T           - 32 and 64 bit floating point numbers *
 *=======================================================================*/
```

And here's the relevant piece for `int32_T`:

```
#ifndef INT32_T
# if   TMW_BITS_PER_INT   == 32
#  define  INT32_T int
# elif TMW_BITS_PER_LONG  == 32
#  define  INT32_T long
# elif TMW_BITS_PER_SCHAR == 32
#  define  INT32_T signed char
# elif TMW_BITS_PER_SHRT  == 32
#  define  INT32_T short
# endif
#endif
#ifdef INT32_T
 typedef INT32_T int32_T;
#endif
```

It gets `TMW_BITS_PER_INT` earlier in the header by comparing `INT_MAX` with various hexadecimal literals, and `0x7FFFFFFFL` wins out.  **Basically, you can use `int32_T`, as described in [the docs for `mxClassID`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxclassid.html), if you are including `tmwtypes.h`.**

However, I doubt MATLAB supports any tool set that uses anything but a 32-bit unsigned integer for `int`.

Comment: Very appreciative of your answer! I've already upvoted and will go through your response in further detail tonight (and most likely accept). Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I have one more mini question: In your opinion, do you think a better approach (rather than casting something with `int32()` in matlab before sending it to the mex function) would be to just send everything as a `double` to the mex function, and then cast it to `int` or `bool` within the mex function itself as necessary? It seems the passing of `double` is very easy and straight forward.

Comment: @jucestain Yes, absolutely for scalars there is no need to use any particular input data type on the MATLAB side.  The above code works without `int32()` conversion in MATLAB.